# WPF TreeView ListBox DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, treeview

I am working on a small project which requires the following needs:

1. A treeView binding data
2. Drag(or RightClick) the treeViewItem from treeview to listbox
3. choose the listboxItem to change the binding data of datagrid

Now I have successfully binding data to treeview, but when I choose the listboxitem, I can't see the datagrid content update, I try to add a textbox to which get the same source, it works.

Could you tell me why this happened ?

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lb_Configuration, Path=SelectedItem}">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock Text="Basic_Param" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" Margin="0,0,0,5" />
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <DataGrid Name="dgBasicInfo" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lb_Configuration, Path=SelectedItem}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="0,0,0,15" BorderThickness="2">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ModelName"  Binding="{Binding Path=ModelName}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="CategoryName" Binding="{Binding Path=CategoryName}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="InputAddress" Binding="{Binding Path=IntputAddress}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="OutputAddress" Binding="{Binding Path=OutputAddress}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DiagAddress" Binding="{Binding Path=DiagAddress}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
<TextBox Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ModelName}" /></Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't bind the ItemsSource property on the DataGrid instance to anything.

Comment: <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lb_Configuration, Path=SelectedItem}"> This don't work for datagrid?

Comment: The DataContext is only the ' data world' your control swims in.

You still have to direct the control(in this case DataGrid) where to get the data specifically

Comment: i tried this: dgBasicInfo.ItemsSource = App.StoreDb.GetProducts(); The datagrid did show data but didn't change  when i choose a different listboxitem

Comment: The thing is if you do it that way, you need to keep assigning it every time the SelectedItem is changing. Registering to the SelectionChanged event on the ListBox will do the trick.

Comment: how should i write the SelectionChanged Event? If i just assigning the itemsSource in the event, the datagrid just changed in the first time.Sorry to be nagging:)

Comment: lb_Configuration.SelectionChanged += ListBox_SelectionCahngedEventHandler;

And let VisualStudio create that method for you.

Comment: I am really new to WPF and  i really need your help, could you please give me your contact so that  i can elaborate my problems?

Comment: Sorry i didn't get the: "This did't work for me?Thanks a lot! I got freak!" comment from earlier. Can you please elaborate what specifically doesn't work at the moment?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried to bind `datagrid.ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Products}"` It doesn't work, I alse tried tried in SelectionChanged `dgBasicInfo.ItemsSource = App.StoreDb.GetProducts();` This give me all the data but i just need to get single item that i choosed

Comment: With regard to: SelectionChanged dgBasicInfo.ItemsSource = App.StoreDb.GetProducts();

What I meant was, that you get in the event handler(SelectionChanged+=EventHandlerName) the selected item.

Then you can go to App.StoreDb to get products for the specific item.

The second option with the Binding, you need to update Products property and the list it contains every time selection changed.

With this way you also need a property in your ViewModel to bind for SelectedItem on the DataGrid.

Comment: Sorry, i am really upset about what i have done, I have searching this for several days and I still cannot make it right, could i just put the  source code on the github so you can help me see it clearly?

Comment: You can use https://pastebin.com/ to post and share your code, no need to upload to github, but its cool if you want to.

Comment: Many thanks to you, here is the repository:[link](https://github.com/Baaaaaarry/PX1_Configurator)

Comment: ProductsView in DataViewModel is not ObservableCollection. Adding Items to it wont change the DataGrid Rows/Items. Maybe change it to ObservableCollection?

Comment: Thanks a lot , I added `NotifyPropertyChanged()` event in the ICollection ProductsView, Finally it works!

Comment: Sorry to bother you,could you please see this problem?[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042194/save-changes-from-datagrid-to-xml-by-dataset]